# Tryton unable to add tax to the product template

Tags: python, tryton

I am  trying to use account-invoice to create a bill and i had successfully created a tax and account and a company with user context properly...following [this example](http://hg.tryton.org/modules/account_invoice/file/170a7faae43f/tests/scenario_invoice.rst) but it appears that when i am appending the tax to the product template and saving the template using `template.save()` i get this error.

`UserError: ('UserError', (u'The value "32" of field "Tax" on "Product Template - Customer Tax" doesn\'t exist.', ''))`

i tried a lot of stuffs and tried with the IRC also...but could not find a solution.

This is the [Traceback](http://dpaste.com/18AAEH3) of errors that i got.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error of not saved properly in the database..my tax instance was not saved properly in the db and hence i had to face this issue.
I got help from IRC regarding this...